# DateTimeControl hide calendar icon

Tags: web-part

Is it possible to hide the calendar icon in the control DateTimeControl.

I have tried to set Calendar to none, but it still shows the icon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I prefer not to deal with server side code in this king of cases.

You could do it easily embedding the following piece of code on the page for SharePoint 2010 (requires jQuery)

```
<script language="javascript">
$(function(){
  $('a[onclick*="clickDatePicker"]').css('display','none');
});
</script>
```

The same way could be easily used for different kings of presentation related customizations.

Comment: i got this error while trying your solutions. " 'style' is null or not an object"

Comment: Please, try to use this. I updated the answer.

Comment: It will disable all calendar icon. What if not to hide a particular one?